# Parse nested list from string that cannot be parsed with ast.literal_eval

Tags: python, list, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I parse a file to a Python list and I encountered a nested list like this:

```
{   1   4{  2a  0.0 }{  3   0.0 }{  4c  0.0 }{  5   0.0 }   }
```

I want to interpret it as a list, yet nested, so I want to be the resulting Python list as follows:

```
[1,4,[2a,0.0],[3,0.0],[4c,0.0],[5,0.0]]
```

I manage to do a correct string of this with a following:

```
l = """{    1   4{  2   0.0 }{  3   0.0 }{  4   0.0 }{  5   0.0 }   }"""
l = l.replace("{\t",",[").replace("\t}","]").replace("{","[").replace("}","]").replace("\t",",")[1:]
```

I can also apply `l.strip("\t")` so that it is a list, but not for a nested, otherwise it will be flattened, which I do not want.

I tried with `ast.literal_eval(l)`, but it fails on strings e.g. `2a`

Comment: I'm confused here. There is one `2a` which becomes `2a` but there's one `4cc` which becomes `4` but on the correct string that you posted, but `2` and `4` does not have any strings to them. What's the right output?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, 4c remains 4c and 2a remains 2a, generally they are strings, i.e. they cannot be parsed with ast without putting into ''''

Comment: Just do split by { then nested split by space

Comment: @E.Serra how do you do this nested split by space? iterate?

Comment: Either use the answer below or a for loop withib the first list. Also i recommend you deleite the empty strings in your list which Will be genérated if you have more than one empty space

Comment: Also i didnt noticr you have nested {{ use pyparser seems the way to go

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pyparsing has a built-in helper `nestedExpr` to help parse nested lists between opening and closing delimiters:

```
>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> nested_braces = pp.nestedExpr('{', '}')
>>> t = """{   1   4{  2a  0.0 }{  3   0.0 }{  4c  0.0 }{  5   0.0 }   }"""
>>> print(nested_braces.parseString(t).asList())
[['1', '4', ['2a', '0.0'], ['3', '0.0'], ['4c', '0.0'], ['5', '0.0']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can develop your own parser using RegEx. In your situation, it is not too difficult. You can parse the enclosing curly brackets, then split the items and evaluate each item recursively.

Here is an example (which is not perfect):

```
import re

RE_BRACE = r"\{.*\}"
RE_ITEM = r"\d+[a-z]+"
RE_FLOAT = r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+"
RE_INT = r"\d+"

find_all_items = re.compile(
    "|".join([RE_BRACE, RE_ITEM, RE_FLOAT, RE_INT]),
    flags=re.DOTALL).findall

def parse(text):
    mo = re.match(RE_BRACE, text, flags=re.DOTALL)
    if mo:
        content = mo.group()[1:-1]
        items = [parse(part) for part in find_all_items(content)]
        return items
    mo = re.match(RE_ITEM, text, flags=re.DOTALL)
    if mo:
        return mo.group()
    mo = re.match(RE_FLOAT, text, flags=re.DOTALL)
    if mo:
        return float(mo.group())
    mo = re.match(RE_INT, text, flags=re.DOTALL)
    if mo:
        return int(mo.group())
    raise Exception("Invalid text: {0}".format(text))
```

**note:** this parser cannot parse `{1 {2} {3} 4}` the right way. You need a recursive parser like `pyparsing` for that.

Demo:

```
s = '''{   1   4{  2a  0.0 }{  3   0.0 }{  4c  0.0 }{  5   0.0 }   }'''

l = parse(s)
print(l)
```

You get:

```
[1, 4, ['2a', 0.0, [3, 0.0, '4c', 0.0], 5, 0.0]]
```