# Split string with comma(,) and exclude list in python

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string

```
'[abc, def, ijk],somedata1,somedata2,somedata3,somedata4'
```

I want to split it as below:

```
[['abc', 'def', 'ijk'], 'somedata1', 'somedata2', 'somedata3', 'somedata4']
```

But when I use `.split(',')` the list also splits

```
'[abc, def, ijk],somedata1,somedata2,somedata3,somedata4'.split(',')
```

Output:

```
['[abc', ' def', ' ijk]', 'somedata1', 'somedata2', 'somedata3', 'somedata4']
```

Is there a way in Python to split with `,` but exclude lists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse nested list from string that cannot be parsed with ast.literal\_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984700/parse-nested-list-from-string-that-cannot-be-parsed-with-ast-literal-eval)

Comment: you have a badly formatted thing - your strings inside need some stringdelimiters. maybe easier to fix this whereever the output is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple trick would be to put quotes around the existing strings to be able to use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
import re

s = '[abc, def, ijk],somedata1,somedata2,somedata3,somedata4'
data = list(ast.literal_eval(re.subn(r'(\w+)', r"'\1'", s)[0]))
```

It gives as expected:

```
[['abc', 'def', 'ijk'], 'somedata1', 'somedata2', 'somedata3', 'somedata4']
```

But beware: any more complex string containing quotes would immediately break this code...

Comment: Thank you , As you said when i have "-" or "/" in my data this breaks

Comment: If they are to be allowed as valid characters in your strings, you can try to replace my pattern in `subn`:  `...subn(r'([-/\w]+)', ...`

Comment: Thank you very much .., for my use case using r'([-/./\w+]+)' helped.